# How do I add +1 to current timezone?

Tags: objective-c, gmt

For example I have this code:

```
[self.df setDateFormat:@"z"]
```

which outputs with `GMT`
I want an output of it as `GMT+1`

or `GMT-4` to `GMT-3`
or `GMT+9` to `GMT+10`

Is that possible with `NSTimeZone`?

Comment: Look for `NSDateFormatter`, the doc and many examples on SO. What have you tried?

Comment: Confusing question. Do you need to append string or offset the date object?

Comment: Yes, it is possible with NSTimeZone. On the other hand it may not even be required bothering about at all, if you just use NSDate accordingly along with NSLocale. But without any code you can hardly expect a good answer to the "how" part of your question

Comment: Did you try my answer  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made it work by doing following.

```
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone] ;
```

to get my local time zone.

In **NSTimeZone** class, there is method called `secondsFromGMT`. From doc:

> which returns the current difference in seconds between the receiver
>   and Greenwich Mean Time.

I'm in GMT+02, in my case it returns 7200. As 7200 in seconds, there is two hours difference between my time zone and Greenwich.

Then, you can create a new time zone using `timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT` methods. As you want to add one hour, you need to add 3600 seconds to GMT. So, here is the code.

```
NSTimeZone *localTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSInteger secondsFromGMT = [localTimeZone secondsFromGMT];
NSTimeZone *timeZoneYouWanted = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:secondsFromGMT + 3600];
```

I've tested **timeZoneYouWanted** is in GMT+03.

Comment: thanks! tweaked it a bit :)